# Belongs to many not attaching data Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables: reviews and guest_reviews. In table reviews I have columns: `id, post_id, user_id, body`. 
In table `reviews_guests` (is pivot table) I have columns: `review_id`, `guest_name`, `guest_email`, `guest_token`.

In model review I have this relation pivot:

```
public function guest()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(static::class, 'reviews_guests');
}
```

When I create review with guest, method attach not working:

```
public function createReview($data = [], $guest = [])
{
    if ($guest) {
        $review = $this->reviews()->create($data);
        $review->guest()->attach($guest);
        $review->save();

        return $review;
    } else {
        $review = $this->reviews()->create($data);
        return $review;
    }

}
```

Why attach not working? On array `guest` and `data` I have data. In table `reviews` review is created, but in `reviews_guests` - not.

Comment: first of all that else is not necessary

Comment: @sietse85 how resolve problem with pivot?